'RANSACRegressor' object has no attribute 'estimator_'
I tried to get the coefficients of the ransac regressor but it always shows that there is no attribute estimator....
            ransac = RANSACRegressor()
            rpm_smoothed_log = np.log(rpm_smoothed)
            try:    
                ransac.fit(rpm_smoothed_log[:, np.newaxis], lw_smoothed)  
                
            except Exception as e:
                print(f'WARNING: {e}')
                
            line_X_log = np.linspace(rpm_smoothed_log.min(), rpm_smoothed_log.max(), 1000)[:, np.newaxis]  
            try: 
                slope = float(ransac.estimator_.coef_[0])    # Steigung 
                print(ransac.estimator_.coeffs)
                intercept = ransac.estimator_.intercept_  # Achsenabschnitt 
                p_regressor = intercept + slope * line_X_log
            except Exception as e:
                print(f'WARNING: {e}')

!continue
WARNING: 'RANSACRegressor' object has no attribute 'estimator_'
I search the internet and i think it should be possibl like that, i have no idea what to try

What version of scikit-learn are you using?

I took a look at https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/main/sklearn/linear_model/_ransac.py.  Seems it should be ransac.estimator; but then you'd have to have passed an estimator in the definition of RANSACRegressor().  Not too sure though.

Version 1.4.2 ; and  i think the problem occurs above because in the ransa.fit function i have the following warning "WARNING: 'numpy.dtype[bool_]' object is not callable" and it happens here in the ransac.py file:
try:  # Not all estimator accept a random_state
estimator.set_params(random_state=random_state)
except ValueError:
pass

in this description it is like i tried to do it: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/linear_model/plot_ransac.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-linear-model-plot-ransac-py
